# How to check if username and password is correct on login when using HTTP Basic?

Tags: java, android, spring, jakarta-ee

I have created a web service that uses HTTP Basic. I am developing an Android application that will present the user a login screen with a textfield for username and another for password. When correct username and password is provided the user will see a new screen.

How can I validate on login that the username and password is correct? Since the dashboard screen that the is taken to after successful login does not by itself needs data from the webservice I can't check if it fails.

Do I have to check against a URL in my application (sending a HEAD request) and see if it fails? Are there any conventions here?

Comment: Your question is unclear.

Comment: How can I check if the username and password entered by an user on login to be correct when I later need to use it when accessing the web service API

Answer (score 0):

Check the response String and look here [HTTP status codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)

You can also use for example a mozilla add-on like `Poster` to check the server response.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i guess you need to apply validations on username and password.

Validation are decided by the server end i.e.  how username and password should be

for instance **USERNAME.**

1) Should not be less than 2 characters and max. length is decided.

2) If Email is to be used as Username then validation for email i.e. mus contains @,. etc.

**for Password**

1) Length of password should not be less than 6 or no to be greater than 20.

2) May or may not contain special characters.

Ask your server end that how they like to receive the username and password and check if user supplied inputs are valid or not , if valid only then make a HTTP call otherwise show user his respective error validation message.

Answer (score 0):

you can send your username and passwords using http get/post method and can validate this at srver side